# Mean & Variance in Distribution

Tags: statistics

Let $S_1, \ldots , S_n$ be the yet-to-be observed survey responses from $n$ individuals, where the event $S_i = 1$ corresponds to the $i$th individual subscribing to Spotify and the event $S_i = 0$ corresponds to the ith individual does not subscribe to Spotify $(i = 1,\ldots, n)$. Assume that $S_1, \ldots , S_n$ are i.i.d. $Ber(\pi)$.

You have a random variable $S = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n S_i$.

I think this is a binomial distribution so my mean is

$\theta =$ probability of success

$n \theta$

and variance is

$n (1- \theta)$

I am trying to figure out what the mean and variance would be if you multiply $S$ by $1/n$

so new random variable is $S = (1/n) \sum\limits_{i=1}^n S_i$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see [this tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) on how to typeset math on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The expected value $E[S]$ is [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) hence
$$
E(\alpha S) = \alpha E(S)
$$
and the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition) is $V[S] = E[(S-E[S])^2]$ hence
$$
V[\alpha S] = E[(\alpha S-\alpha E[S])^2] = E[\alpha^2( S-E[S])^2]  = \alpha^2 E[(S-E[S])^2] = \alpha^2 V[S].
$$

This extents to your case where
$$
E\left[\frac{1}{n}S\right] = \frac{n\theta}{n} = \theta\\
V\left[\frac{1}{n}S\right] = \frac{n\theta(1-\theta)}{n^2} = \frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n}.
$$

Note that there is a typo where you state the [variance of the binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Variance).

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**
Note that
$$
ES=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n ES_i
$$
by linearity of expectation. Now use the fact that the $S_i$ are identically distributed. Moreover since the $S_i$ are independent
$$
V(S)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^nV(S_i)
$$
where $V(S)$ denotes variance of $S$.